# Initialize once_flag?

Tags: c++, c++11

What is a `once_flag`supposed to be initialized to? I've tried `false` and `0`, and both have given errors similar to below (below is `0`):

```
no viable conversion from 'int' to 'std::once_flag'
```

Here's how I am trying to use it. (I consider it bad style to *not* initialize statics even though the language initializes them, so I'd really prefer to have something there).

```
MyClass& GetMyClass()
{
    static std::once_flag flag;
    static MyClass cls;

    std::call_once(flag, []() {
        // Initialize class
    });

    return cls;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**

If we look at the draft C++ standard section `30.4.4.1` *Struct once_flag* we can see the constructor is defined as:

```
constexpr once_flag() noexcept;
```

since it is a *constexpr* your *static* instance will be *statically initialized* and we can see an example in section `30.4.4.2` *Function call_once* that uses a *static* instance:

```
void g() {
 static std::once_flag flag2;
 std::call_once(flag2, initializer());
}
```

**Original**

If we look at the documentation to [std::once_flag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag) it says:

```
once_flag();

Cnstructs an once_flag object. The internal state is set to indicate that no function
has been called yet.
```

and if we look further at the document documentation for [call_once](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) we see the following example which demonstrates how to use `std::once_flag`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::once_flag flag; 

void do_once()
{
    std::call_once(flag, [](){ std::cout << "Called once" << std::endl; });
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(do_once);
    std::thread t2(do_once);
    std::thread t3(do_once);
    std::thread t4(do_once);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}
```

with the following expected output:

```
Called once
```

Comment: Thanks Shafik. For some reason, I thought it was a flag. I did not think realize it was an object until you and Bryan mentioned it.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question has been answered elsewhere, as an alternative to the code you posted, you can also do this instead:

```
// private function in anonymous namespace or something
MyClass& initMyClass() {
    static MyClass c;
    /* initialize c */
    return c;
}
```

and then have clients call

```
MyClass& GetMyClass() {
    static MyClass& c = initMyClass();
    return c;
}
```

because static initializations are thread safe now in C++11. And then you don't have to mess with `call_once` or anything.

Answer (score 2):

what are you trying to do? you cannot initialize `std::once_flag` with any value because it only has one constructor that does not take any arguments.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag

> once_flag(); Constructs an once_flag object. The internal state is set
>   to indicate that no function has been called yet.

BTW, what is the reason that you consider not initialize statics variable is a bad style?

Comment: Thanks Bryan. For some reason, I thought it was a flag. I did not think realize it was an object until you and Shafik mentioned it.

Comment: "what is the reason that you consider not initialize statics variable is a bad style" - Code audits. When I scan the code, its easier to spot non-statics that are not initialized. Plus, I don't want the junior guys confusing the rules (so the rule is "initialize everything"). The compiler and optimizer can remove the initialization if its inclined to do so.

Answer (score 1):

`ONCE_FLAG_INIT`

EDIT: C only, not C++. Defined in `<threads.h>`.

Comment: what is this? any link at least?

Comment: It's the static initializer for `once_flag`. Also usable in C.

Comment: Do you know the header (is it also `<mutex>`)? I'm getting an error under Clang, `-std=c++11`, and `-stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: Whoops, I **knew** I should have looked it up. It's C only, not C++. `<threads.h>` in C11.

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to comment that it looked like *C* only, I was going to dive into the standard for it.